# Servlet initializing database parameters from web.xml

Tags: java, xml, servlets, context-param

I have problem with my context-params in my web application. My methodes

```
 getServletContext().getInitParameter("pass");
```

Are returning null.
Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Log4jWebDemo1</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j-config-location</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>url</param-name>
        <param-value>dbc:postgresql://localhost/OlapTest</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>name</param-name>
        <param-value>org.postgresql.Driver</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>usr</param-name>
        <param-value>postgres</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>pass</param-name>
        <param-value>admin</param-value>
    </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello World</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.javastart.servlets.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>

  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello World</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And my servlet:

```
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       private String url2 = ""; 
       private String driver = ""; 
       private String username = ""; 
       private String password = ""; 

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        url2 = getServletContext().getInitParameter("url");
        driver = getServletContext().getInitParameter("name");
        username = getServletContext().getInitParameter("usr");
        password = getServletContext().getInitParameter("pass");

        DatabaseHandling d1 = new DatabaseHandling(driver,url2,username,password);

        d1.createConnection(out);

        }
}
```

After executing my application it throws

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you paste the full exception stack trace ?

Comment: Already did it my friend

Comment: can you show  DatabaseHandling class  code

Comment: Its redundant I think, when I manualy put string values where I am executing `getServletContext().getInitParameter();` The app works fine

Comment: before calling  DatabaseHandling d1 = new DatabaseHandling(driver,url2,username,password); this line just print all string values.

Comment: null null null null

Comment: you are getting null values from web.xml , so please verify your web.xml is perfect.

Comment: I ll edit topic and paste my full web.xml

Comment: Why don't you use a datasource handled by the server ?

Comment: Its my third day with servlets. I have to do task like this. I dont know whats wrong in my code, all internet tutorials look almost the same.

Comment: have you tried ServletConfig demo

Comment: yes, I wrote init() methode too, everything ends with same result

Comment: When I restarted my eclipse, `getServletContext().getInitParameter();` returns right values, but still I get an error like this **java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for dbc:postgresql://localhost/OlapTest**

Comment: Have you used postgresql jar

Comment: The problem is solved, It looks like there is need to restart not only Tomcat, but  IDE too after editing web.xml. Thank's everybody for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be few possibilities that leads to the NullPointerException exception

1. PostgresSQl driver(**jar file**) library is not added in your classpath.
2. You need to share your DatabaseHandling class so as to check the code written for connecting with DB.
3. change the web.xml as below:

   `<context-param>
       <param-name>url</param-name>
       <param-value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/OlapTest</param-value>
   </context-param>`

**J** is missing. Check the error it says **dbc**.